# nrwl NX init fails in make-angular-cli-faster init

Tags: migration, angular-cli, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have an existing angular cli project (V12.2.16).

Im trying to migrate it to an NX standalone Application with the command :

```
npx nx init
```

Im getting an error:

```
Error: Command failed: npx --yes make-angular-cli-faster@latest init
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:790:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:863:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\harmony-encore-fe\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\init.js:22:46)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Code\harmony-encore-fe\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:167:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Code\harmony-encore-fe\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:163:16)
    at Object.initHandler (C:\Code\harmony-encore-fe\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\init.js:12:20)
    at C:\Code\harmony-encore-fe\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\nx-commands.js:207:71
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 10148,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

I tried running the command `npx --yes make-angular-cli-faster@latest init`

Standalone but it gives me the following error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any suggestions on how to solve such an issue ?

Thanks.

Tried to migrate to an  NX standalone application and was expecting to migrate succcesfyly but the result was an error thrown from NX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which NodeJs version are you using?

I had the same error while I was running `npx nx init` on NodeJs 14.19.3 and it works fine running it on NodeJs 16.16.0.

I hope it helps.